# NodeJS Mail listener2 is downloading email signature images as attachments in outlook, how to stop it?

Tags: javascript, node.js, outlook, nodes

I am using NPMs mail-listener2 package to go through my outlook mails and download attachments in the mails. But it is also downloading signature images such as mailer's logo and company images as an attachment. How do I set it up to only download the actual attachment attached to the email and not the signature emails. 
Attachment can be pdf or png or jpg.

Answer (score 0):

Signature images *are* actual attachments, they are just referenced by the HTML body. It is your responsibility to parse the HTML body to see if img elements reference the attachments, either through the content-id (cid attribute for the img tags), content location, or by file name.

Comment: Thanks for that info, can you please give me a little more details about how you would do it? In my case the incoming email doesn't have any specific format. Different users might send in different formats and their signatures might vary. How wold I make my node server only download the actual attachment and not the signature images? I am using Outlook mail for receiving mails. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for "contentDisposition" property of attachment object.

```
attachment.contentDisposition
```

It's value can be either "inline" if it is part of email body or "attachment" if it is an actual attachment.